# Pass data from Laravel $collection to jquery loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Hi everyone this is a Laravel issue. I'm working on a directory site. I am trying to solve a problem like this: I need to populate an open street map with markers that are handled as javascript variables like this:

```
var mapMarkers = [
{
    title: "Paolo",
    address: "Troy South End, 264 E. Berkley St, Boston",
    lat: 42.3432809,
    lng: -71.06297789999996,
    img: "assets/images/listings/1.jpg",
    category: "Restaurants",
    icon: "icon-dinner",
    featText: "~ $18-$90",
    rating: "4.9",
    link: "#"
},
{
    title: "Paolo",
    address: "5347 N Clark St, Chicago, IL",
    lat: 41.9794495,
    lng: -87.6679747,
    img: "assets/images/listings/2.jpg",
    category: "Restaurants",
    icon: "icon-dinner",
    featText: "Best fried chicken of the town",
    rating: "4.2",
    link: "#"
},
{
    title: "Paolo",
    address: "171 E Broadway, New York, NY",
    lat: 40.7138292,
    lng: -73.98966669999999,
    img: "assets/images/listings/5.jpg",
    category: "Restaurants",
    icon: "icon-dinner",
    featText: "Promotional Lunch $45",
    rating: "4.1",
    link: "#"
}
   ];
```

The problem is that I have this data inside a Laravel collection and I'm looking for the best way to passing them to the javascript:

```
    var mapMarkers = [
{
    title: $companies->name,
    address: $companies->address,
   ............
},
```

Can someone help to understand the best practice to solve this issue?

Comment: Your want [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) but as the properties names look like they're not normalised your need to build it out again in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similarly to Eloquent objects, collections can be serialized to JSON (Javascript objects) by calling the `toJson()` method. So, `$companies->toJson()` should give you what you need.

In a Blade template, you can "print" out the companies' json format like this:

```
<script>
    var mapMarkers = {!! $companies->toJson() !!};
</script>
```

So, now when you use mapMarkers in your javascript code, it's like using the `$companies` collection in PHP.

It also looks like your fields don't match up (`title: $companies->name` in your example). To make the returned json include `title` instead of `name`, you can map over all of the companies, and set the title field to the company name. With that, the above example would look like this:

```
<script>
    var mapMarkers = {!! $companies->map(function ($company) { $company->title = $company->name; return $company; })->toJson() !!};
</script>
```

Mapping over a collection creates a new collection with the value returned from the map callback function.

You can look at these methods in the Laravel docs: [toJson()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-tojson) and [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map).

Comment: This is for me the solution! And your method don't make other calls to Ajax. Great! Many Many Thks

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax, you can accomplish this because normally, Collections and arrays and automatically returned as JSON by Laravel, also collection has `->toJson()` method which you can use to return the response, then`JSON.parse(the_response)` to give you a javascript object.

Comment: Yes of coruse. But i have already a return view() action in my Controller, so i need to create another method and another call. The collection is already used in the same view so data is already there...